# Independent coin tosses, Hypothesis testing

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have 10 independent coin tosses with probability p for heads.
I'm testing the null hypothesis
$H_0: p=1/2$
Versus the alternative
$H_1 : p > 1/2 $

$W$ is the number of heads in the 10 coin tosses.
We accept $H_0$ if $W \leq c$ else reject $H_0$
Decide c so that $\alpha = 0.05$

I started off saying $W$ is $binomial(10,½)$ so the probability of type I errors is:

$P(Type I Error)=P(Reject H_0 \mid H_0) = P(RejectH_0 \mid p=½) = P(W >c\mid p=½)=\sum\limits_{k=c+1}^{\infty} P(W=k)$

$And because of W being binomial(10,½)

$=\sum\limits_{k=c+1}^{10} 0.5^k 0.5^{10-k}={(10-c)}/1024 $

And so because of us wanting $\alpha =0.05$ we choose a c so that
$(10-c)/1024 \leq \alpha $

So I get
$c=10-\alpha*1024=-41.2$

Which seems wrong to me, where did i go wrong in my thought process? Because if c=-41.2 then i would never be able to say the coin is fair and accept the null hypothesis

Comment: Check probabilities for binomial distrbution.

Comment: Using the discrete distribution BINOM(10,.5) you can't get exactly $\alpha = 0.05.$ In R: $P(X \ge 9|p=1/2) \approx 0.011,$ computed as `sum(dbinom(9:10, 10, 1/2))` which returns 0.01074219 and $P(X \ge 8|p = 1/2) \approx 0.055)$ with code `sum(dbinom(8{10, 10, 1/2))`, which returns 0.0546875. // Exact normal computations on a calculator are feasible, You can try to sweep the discreteness under the rug by using a normal approximation, but that doesn't change the truth.